# How to get different hover overlays on images in a gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a grid of 5 pictures, one of them is larger than the others, while 4 of them are the same size and are aligned in a square. I have one hover effect working for the larger size image, but when I try to make the other images have the same effect with different text it does not work. How do I fix this?

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

.hlogo {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.hlogo a {
  color: #092140;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #092140;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #F24738;
}

/* Grid */

.featured {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}

.featured>div {
  text-align: center;
}

.fmain {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  position: relative;
}

.fmain img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main1 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main2 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main2 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main3 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.main3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main4 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.main4 img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Overlay on images in grid */

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
  background-color: #F24738;
}

.hover-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fmain:hover,
.main1:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hlogo">
  <a href="Home">Hidden Listen</a>
</div>

<!-- Header Links -->
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="Home">Home</a>
  <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
  <a href="Artists">Artists</a>
</div>

<!-- Grid of Home page -->
<div class="featured">
  <div class="fmain">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/marvel1.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h1 class="hover-text">Text hover shit</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main1">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/fantasy.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h1 class="hover-text">Text hover shit</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main2">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/No Dope on Sundays.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
  </div>
  <div class="main3">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/Scum Tyler.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
  </div>
  <div class="main4">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/syre.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're triggering the hover when you hover over `fmain`, rather than the individual images. Is that intentional?

Comment: When I hover over the first large picture I want an area just over that picture to turn a color with text over, and same with the other four pictures. I got one to work, which is the larger fmain one, but the way I tried to do it now the whole page gets covered instead. So what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the individual pictures to get that hover effect. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

```
<div class="main1">
    <img src="/img/Album Covers/fantasy.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
    <div class="overlay1">
      <h1 class="hover-text">Text hover shit</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and css

```
.main1:hover >.overlay1 {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, for some reason it made the whole page glitch out and random hovers started to appear over the wrong areas.

Comment: I got it to work! I just had to set my positions for all of them. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify position for main1234 divs

```
.main1, .main2,.main3, .main4 {
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML

```
<div class="featured">
  <figure class="main fmain">
    <img src="" alt="Album Cover">
    <figcaption class="overlay">
      <h1 class="hover-text">Text hover shit</h1>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="main main1">
    <img src="" alt="Album Cover">
    <figcaption class="overlay">
      <h1 class="hover-text">Text hover shit</h1>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="main main2">
    <img src="" alt="Album Cover">
    <figcaption class="overlay">
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="main main3">
    <img src="" alt="Album Cover">
    <figcaption class="overlay">
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="main main4">
    <img src="" alt="Album Cover">
    <figcaption class="overlay">
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.featured {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: 0 30px;

}

.main{
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3em; /* Remove Padding when adding image */

}
.main img{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fmain {
  grid-column: 1/ 3;
  grid-row: 1/7;
  background: #ccc;
}
.main1 {
  grid-column: 4 / 3;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  background: red;
}

.main2 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  background: orange;
}

.main3 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4/7;
  background: green;
}

.main4 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4/7;
  background: red;
}

/* Overlay on images in grid */

.main .overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
  background: #F24738;
}

.hover-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main:hover .overlay,
.main:focus .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
```